# Use Fetch-Mock to return test Blob

Tags: javascript, fetch-mock

I have a fetch which receives a file from a server and I am trying to mock the fetch for my tests with `fetch-mock`.
Using this code I can mock the endpoint and place the blob in the body:

```
const blob = new Blob(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
fetchMock.once('*', {body: blob}, {sendAsJson: false});
```

The code that is being tested is:

```
fetch(url).then( ( response ) => {
            console.log(response);
            return response.blob();
        } ).then( ( blob ) => {
            console.log(blob);
        } )
```

I can see that the Blob is on the body of the request

```
Body {
    url: '/mock/url',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { _headers: {} },
    ok: true,
    body: Blob {},
    bodyUsed: false,
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    _raw: [],
    _abort: false }
```

But running the test throws the error:

```
    TypeError: response.blob is not a function
```

Running the code with a server returns a valid Blob into the final `.then`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the solution was that `fetch-mock` has a peer dependency on `node-fetch` which is used during the jest tests. I had an older version of `node-fetch` pulled in by another library.

So directly requiring the latest `node-fetch` in my `package.json` solved this issue.